# Dropdownlist is taking long time to load in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I'm using vb6 and sql server.in which on the form load I'm filling 4 combobox.But its taking 10 to 12 minutes to load the form.
My code is as follows:
Can anybody help me to make the form load fast?

```
Public Sub fillCombo(Id As String, Name As String, Table As String, obj As Object, Optional cond As String)
    Dim rsF  As New ADODB.Recordset
    With rsF
    If .State = adStateOpen Then .Close
    If cond = "" Then
    .Open "Select " & Id & "," & Name & " From " & Table & " Order by " & Name, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    Else
    .Open "Select " & Id & "," & Name & " From " & Table & " Where " & cond & " Order by " & Name, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    End If
    obj.Clear
    'obj.AddItem ""
    While Not .EOF
    obj.AddItem .Fields(1)
    obj.ItemData(obj.NewIndex) = .Fields(0)
    .MoveNext
    Wend
    .Close
    End With
    End Sub
```

function call is as follows:
    fillCombo "JobId", "JobName", "Jobs", cboJob

Comment: When you debug it, which line is taking the most time to run. `Open`?

Comment: how many items in the combo boxes?

Comment: Only 500 Items are there. While loop is taking time.

Comment: The obsolete `While/Wend` construct is slow but not that slow.  Try using a client-side, read-only, forward-only cursor and see if that helps any.

Comment: Could it be a poor connection? If you comment out the AddItem and ItemData calls does it make any difference?

Comment: @Bob77 There is no such thing as a client-side, read-only, forward-only cursor.  Client-side cursors can only be static.  (Also, the CursorLocation property trumps the CursorType property.)  However, I believe you're otherwise correct.

Comment: True enough, you'd have to use a server-side cursor for that and you'd probably want to increase the Recordset's CacheSize.  But a Keyset cursor with write locking wouldn't be my first choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (I believe) is that you are using a server-side recordset.  When you do this, you are making one round trip to the server for each iteration of your loop, which is, as you have found, glacially slow.

The solution is to create a client-side recordset.  That sends the data from the server to the client in one go.  Keep in mind that client-side recordsets are always static; if you set the CursorType to adOpenKeyset the CursorLocation to adUseClient, the latter will override the former and your CursorType will still be adOpenStatic.

Here's a mod to your code, with various improvements (in particular, with your atrocious indenting corrected; you might consider being a bit nicer to the poor folks who have to work with your code down the line when you write it):

```
Public Sub fillCombo(Id As String, Name As String, Table As String, obj As Object, Optional cond As String)

    Dim sql As String
    Dim rsF As ADODB.Recordset 'Don't use "As New" in VB6, it's slow

    'sql variable with ternary conditional (IIf) is cleaner way to do what you want
    sql = "Select " & Id & "," & Name & " From " & Table & IIf(cond = "", "", " Where " & cond) & " Order by " & Name
    Set rsF = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rsF
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient 'Client-side, static cursor

        'If .State = adStateOpen Then .Close --Get rid of this: if you just created rsF, it can't be open, so this is a waste of processor cycles

        .Open sql, Cn 'Much prettier, yes?  :)
        obj.Clear 'All this is fine
        Do Until .EOF
            obj.AddItem .Fields(1)
            obj.ItemData(obj.NewIndex) = .Fields(0)
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```